# Laptop Gray Screen, but works with external monitor

Tags: windows-7, laptop, display

I was working on my laptop, when suddenly the entire OS froze and I had to force-shut down the computer (I didn't for long, I don't know if it would have blue screened). When I turned the computer on, the whole screen was gray:

[image: Gray Laptop]

...a few weeks later, it's still like that. However, plugging in an external monitor DOES work, and nothing else seems to be wrong with it, except a battery problem I've always had: it will sometimes click and shut down without warning when not plugged in. What could be wrong? How can I try to fix it? Is my best option to just order a new screen, or is that not even a guaranteed fix?

It is an hp EliteBook 8440p and I have no warranty.

Thanks a ton!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The Problem:**  What you describe is probably either a screen connector or screen circuitry.  The relationship to the OS freezing isn't likely to be coincidence.  It's possible that whatever failed, related to the screen, caused a momentary short or signal that led the the OS freeze.

**Possibilities:**  If the problem is inside the top half of your laptop (the screen), it is generally not cost effective to try to fix it.  Typically, the screen is replaced.

The problem could be with the connection between the screen and the system board.  Sometimes this is an actual connector and sometimes it is a ribbon cable from the screen that slips into a socket in the bottom half of the laptop.  This is often repairable but it usually requires some laptop disassembly and technical proficiency (and possibly specialized tools).

Screen replacement or connection repair is not a task for novices.  If you're experienced and have the tools, open it up and inspect the connection.  See if it is something obvious, like the ribbon cable pulled out of the socket or a visible problem with the connector.  Assess whether you can fix it.  Beyond that, the fact that you asked this question is probably an indication that you don't have the training and equipment to do a diagnosis and repair or screen replacement.

**Service Options:**  This means potentially getting it serviced.  This comes down to an economic decision, which may vary with who does the work (e.g., sending it into HP authorized service vs. local shop).  They may give you a flat price for screen repair, or there might be a diagnostic fee to open it up and figure out the problem, after which there would be additional costs for parts and labor to fix the problem.  Check what your actual costs would be.

I did a quick online search and it looks like the entire top half of the laptop retails for around $160; the guts under the plastic shell is in the range of $110-$130.  That's just for the part, not the labor.  These kinds of repairs often carry a warranty of around 90 days and sometimes, the repair parts are refurbished parts, particularly if it is an older model.  These are details to check on.  For these reasons, major repairs are often not a great investment.

**Repair vs. Replacement:**  I don't know which particular model you have but it looks like new 8440p laptops retail in the range of around $200-$400 depending on what's under the hood.  At the low end of the range, fixing your laptop would cost as much as a new one (or more), if the screen needs replacement.  At the high end, the repair would make a serious down payment on a new one.  If your laptop is 4 or 5 years old, it could well be at the age where other components could start to go (like the keyboard or hard disk).  All of these components can be replaced but you will end up paying the cost of a new computer to continue to own an end-of-life old one (with no warranty).

**Other Options:**

- Continue to use it with an external monitor (zero cost).
- Look at buying a new one and cannibalizing parts from the current one.  You might be able to use the RAM to beef up a new one, or stick the hard drive in an external enclosure and use it as an extra drive for backup or a similar purpose.  The power adapter would be a spare.
- Buy a new one and save the current one as an emergency backup machine.

So that's some perspective on the choices.

Comment: One other thought--talk to HP tech support.  With a lot of their equipment, if it fails outside of warranty they will offer you a discount on a new machine to keep you as a customer.  You need to compare the discount to what you would pay at a big box store or Amazon, but it can be a pretty good deal.  If you add the discount to what you would save on a repair, and choose a model that is currently on sale, you may be able to get a new machine for not much extra money.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem too with two of my previous laptops. It is probably a video connector problem to the screen of your laptop.
If you still have a warranty running on the laptop, return it, it should be no problem to fix it. If you don't you can try to replace the video connector (if it isn't soldered into the board).

Make sure you backup your data before doing anything!

Comment: he said he connected an external display and worked, Which I think the problem should be from monitor not the video card ...

Comment: @TechLife Doh, of course. I shouldn't be making answers before breakfast =/... Updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I went ahead and corrected what looked like a remnant from your prior change.  If you disagree, roll it back.