# Laptop screen 'blank' , but with weird glowing colors

Tags: laptop, display

After playing a game my laptop hibernated to prevent overheating (that's the message it gave me). I let it stand for a minute or so, rebooted and continued gaming. It hibernated again, so I just stopped playing for that day.
(I can't remember this happening before, but it was quite hot, both the laptop (of course) and my room).

A few days later I suddenly got problems while booting my laptop with my screen. It went sort of blank, but not black. I couldn't see anything on the screen except for some vertical bars. They were sort of glowing. The screen became brighter, and then less bright again (see the photo below).

Sometimes it shows up again normally when I get to the login screen (windows 10), sometimes it doesn't. Just now I rebooted twice, the third time it worked allright (and in this case: from the start).

Usually once it works, it keeps working untill I leave it for a little while and close the lid, or shut it down and reboot later. Once though it went bad while I was watching it. The screen just froze, and it slowely became more "foggy", as if the screen transitioned between two slides. From my desktop with a window to the 'glowing' screen with the vertical bars.

I have a photo made with my phone below. The curved stripes (especially on the top right) seem to come from my bad phone camera, but you can clearly see the difference in lighting on my screen (brighter in the center) and the vertical bars everywhere.

So finally my question:
- Can I fix this? Or maybe go to some computer shop and let them fix it for me?

I haven't tried plugging in an external monitor yet. I guess I could buy an external monitor + keyboard and use that isntead, but I'd rather keep using it just as a laptop.

Also, if this is not a problem with hardware: I have a backup and am willing to reinstal the OS.

I tried shutting it down, disconnect the power and remove the battery and then press the power button for 30 seconds, but that didn't help (read this somewhere on the internet).

Some more info:

- Brand: HP pavilion 15-p035nd
- I have two graphics cards/drivers, an Intel chip and an NVIDEA GeForce.
- (this probably won't matter, but): I'm running f.lux to make the screen light a bit less blue.
- The laptop is like 2 years old.
- I'm running windows 10. I can also boot to Ubuntu, but haven't done so in a while.

[image: Photo of laptop]

Comment: I searched and couldn't find something related, but now I see this question: http://superuser.com/questions/856985/laptop-gray-screen-but-works-with-external-monitor?rq=1

Reading it now, possibly related.

Comment: Can you try an external screen to see if you get any graphic glitches on that?

Comment: External screen seems to work just fine.